# Visual C++ stop textbox cursor movement

Tags: c++, textbox, visual-c++-2012

In visual c++ is there anyway to stop the user from using the arrow keys to move the cursor in a textbox? I've got a textbox for a phone number set up like "()-" and when you click or enter text it automatically re-positions the cursor to the next space to enter a number, but you can still use the arrow keys to re-position the cursor which lets you delete the parenthesis and dash.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass it and prevent the arrow key events from reaching the edit box. How to accomplish this would depend on what framework (or lack thereof) you are using.